Route to BMS system from external to internal
Block of flats, routers use the top router for WAN, there is a BMS on the LAN side of the top router.
I can ping from flat routers to lets say a laptop in the top router subnet (as the flat's wan sits on the LAN of top router).
Problem im having is the BMS needs to create a connection to a panel in the flat thus requiring some routing / firewall changes.
So on the top router i've done a static route to say to get to the VLAN flat side go via that router, traceroute looks correct.
I've also for testing allowed in firewall any / any / any to the vlan subnet, but I cannot ping.
Anything im missing?
I'll try to attach some network diagram to help - https://ibb.co/sQv8dvp


Can you successfully ping computers or other kinds of devices inside the flat network, to rule out problems with the BMS devices themselves? (Please don't completely disable the firewall. Add specific rules for what traffic you need.)

Are you using NAT and where?

yeah, so each router standard NAT - like I say I can ping upstream (by design)
Dont worry about firewall rules this is a concept so I want to make sure connectivity before I lock it down.

I was able to ping a test device in the flat network from the router so I know its live and responding to icmp.

TLA's can be quite confusing at time, for me "BMS" is short for Battery Management System - migjt it be the same here? Regardless of what: May I suggest to spell it out at least the first time it is used.

@Hannu Building management system - door entry lets flat user know someone is at main door forexample
